# Irreducible decomposition of standard complex representation of an alternating group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, representation-theory

Let $A_n = \{\sigma \in S_n : \mathrm{sign}\;\sigma=1\}$ be alternating group.

Let $\rho: A_n \to \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^n) $ stand for standart complex representation of $A_n$ defined by 
$$ \rho(\sigma)(e_i) = e_{\sigma(i)} $$
where $e_i$ is a standart basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

It is well known fact that simmilar representation for $S_n$ decomposes to sum of two irreducible ones for subspaces 
$$
U_1 = \mathbb{C}\sum^n_{i=1} e_i 
$$
$$
U_0 = \left\{ v \in \mathbb{C}^n \bigg|  \sum^n_{i=1} v_i = 0  \right\}
$$

But will  $U_0$  still be irreducible for $A_n$?

> Are there any invariant irreducible subspaces of $U_0$ which exist only for $A_n$?

Clearly $A_2$ is trivial and $A_3$ can't have any irreducible representations of degree 2 as $|A_3| = 3 < 4 = 2^2$.
This indicates that there must be one-dimensional invariant subspace of $U_0$
But I don't know how to find equation for this subspace.

Comment: One-dimensional subspaces are eigenspaces, so they at least come from linear algebra.

Comment: I understand that $U_0$ always must be invariant, but I can't comprehend how it is irreducible for $A_3$ which should not hav irreducible representations of degree bigger than 1.

Comment: @anon I think I got what you meant

Comment: If $n > 3$ then $U_0$ is irreducible under the action of $A_n$. Note that $A_n$ acts $2$-transitively when $n>3$ and there is a general result that the permutation representation over ${\mathbb C}$ of any $2$-transitive group is the sum of the trivial representation and an irreducible module.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks, this is useful.

Comment: @DerekHolt Does the general result involving 2-transitive action is also valid over general fields in nonmodular case ??

Comment: Yes, this has now been discussed and answered in your MO question.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, when $n=3$ there is an invariant subspace of $U_0$ of dimension $1$. It is generated by $(1,j,j^2)$.

Comment: Yes I think it comes from the intersection of eigenspaces of $\rho(123)$  and $\rho(132)$ as @anon suggested.

Comment: I will add that $j = - \frac{1}{2}  + \frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}$